# Minimizing the sum of rational functions over simplex

Tags: inequality, optimization, rational-functions

Let

$$f(x) := \frac{2x+1}{x^2+3}$$

I would like to solve the following optimization problem

$$ \begin{array}{ll} \underset {x_1, x_2, x_3} {\text{minimize}} & f(x_1) + f(x_2) + f(x_3) \\ \text{subject to} & x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 3 \\ & x_1, x_2, x_3 \in [0,3] \end{array} $$

I am not sure how to find that since $f(x)$ is concave and convex over the given interval. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: @eyeballfrog I dont know them

Comment: Are you sure you want to mimize? I ask since in the given interval, there is a unique maximum, whereas minima are obtained at the boundary.

Comment: @Andreas. Indeed I was. Otherwise I would have used Jensen

Comment: Given how nice the objective function is, I wonder if its niceness can be exploited

Comment: Is there a pure calc solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have, for all $x \in [0, 3]$,
$$\frac{2x + 1}{x^2 + 3} - \frac{x + 4}{12} = \frac{x(x + 7)(3 - x)}{12(x^2 + 3)} \ge 0.$$

Thus, we have, for all $x_1, x_2, x_3 \in [0, 3]$ with $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 3$,
$$f(x_1) + f(x_2) + f(x_3)
\ge \frac{x_1 + 4}{12} + \frac{x_2 + 4}{12} + \frac{x_3 + 4}{12} 
= \frac54$$
with equality if $x_1 = 0, x_2 = 0, x_3 = 3$ and permutations.

Thus, the minimum if $\frac54$.

Comment: Nice! errata: the minimum *is* $\frac54$;  $x_1 = 0, x_2 = 0, x_3 = 3$ *and permutations*.

Comment: Hmmm. That is smart. Can you explain your motivation for the first line?

Comment: @River Li could you please explain to me how one should come up with $\frac{2x+1}{x^{2}+3}-\frac{x+4}{12}\ge0$.....It kinda looks like tangent line trick but It isn't

Comment: @Helixglich there is no general, "magic intuition" that help solve all problems. Most of the times, it's experience of solving similar problems in the past. 

As for the guess, since you have a liner sum constraint, it would be a reasonable first attempt to look for:
$$\dfrac{2x+1}{x^2+3}\geq ax + b$$
to hold for $x\in[0,3].$ This means that the cubic after expanding should have factors $x(x-3)$ and another linear factor and in that case it turns out to be useful. This is not guaranteed in general and if the problem was harder/tighter, then it would naturally require more advanced stuff.

Comment: @Helixglich As explained by dezdichado, here we used linear function lower bound for the objective.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for reviving the thread. But it is not quite clear to me that you need a factor of x(x-3) in the cubic. Do you mind elaborating on that @dezdichado

Comment: @Helixglich The simple way is to plot $\frac{2x+1}{x^2+3}$ on $[0, 3]$. We can see that the line connecting $(0, 1/3)$ and $(3, 7/12)$ is the desired linear function lower bound.

Comment: "[...] and permutations" because in the inequality $$\frac{2x + 1}{x^2 + 3} - \frac{x + 4}{12} = \frac{x(x + 7)(3 - x)}{12(x^2 + 3)} \ge 0$$ equality is attained at $0$ and $3$, right?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes.

Comment: @Helixglich I phrased it as "should" have. As in, if this simple idea were to work, then there is "probably" the factor $x(3-x)$ multiplied another non-negative linear factor. Your inequality is an equality when the variables are at the endpoint of the interval $[0,3]$ and that's a strong hint for the factor. 

If the equality was attained at like $x_1=x_2=x_3 = 2,$ then I would expect a factor $(x-2)$ in there somewhere. But again, not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

Uhhh. I didn't realize that River Li was just using tangent line trick...I had nothing to do so I present a proof that if probably wrong but I can't find why....
Let $f(x) = \frac{2x+1}{x^2+3}$. Therefore, $f'(x) = \frac{-2x^2-2x+6}{(x^2+3)^2}$. Therefore $f''(x) = \frac{4x^3+6x^2-36x-6}{(x^2+3)^3}$
We are now ready to locate the inflection points of $f(x)$
$$f''(x) = 0 \leftrightarrow 4x^3+6x^2-36x-6 = 0$$
Since \begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
x& f''(x)\\ \hline
 -4&-22 \\ \hline
 -3&48 \\ \hline
 0&-6  \\ \hline
 3&48  \\ \hline
\end{array}
And clearly $-4,-3,0,3$ are not zeros. From intermediate value theorem follows that there is only one root of the cubic in the interval $[0,3]$ and thus one inflection point ot $f(x)$.

We will now use something known as n - 1 EV ([Theorem 2.8](https://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/Ineq/en.pdf)) $\leftarrow$ Please someone check if I am using this correctly

We now just need to optimise:
$F(a) =f(a) + f(a) + f(3-2a)$ subject to $a\in[0,1.5]$

$$F(a) = 2*\frac{2a+1}{a^2+3}+\frac{2(3-2a)+1}{(3-2a)^2+3}\Longrightarrow F'(a) = \frac{4a^2-14a+9}{4(a^2-3a+3)^2}-4*\frac{a^2+a-3}{(a^2+3)^2}$$
We will now find the critical points in $F'(a)$ subject to $a\in[0,1.5]$

Since $a\in \mathbb{R}$ the function is always defined and we will only need to check $F'(a) = 0$
$$F'(a) = 0 \leftrightarrow \frac{4a^2-14a+9}{4(a^2-3a+3)^2}=4\frac{a^2+a-3}{(a^2+3)^2}$$
$$12a^6-66a^5+63a^4+324a^3-954a^2+1134a-513=0$$
From some testing we get the only real root in the interval is $a = 1$ (I did Sturm's method with wolfram if anyone knows a method to do this by hand please please reply ;D )

Now onto our last step:

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
a& F'(a)\\ \hline
 0&\frac{5}{4} \\ \hline
 1&\frac{9}{4} \\ \hline
 1.5&1.85714 \\ \hline
\end{array}

And finally we conclude that the minimum is $\frac{5}{4}$ with the equality cases being permutations of (0,0,3)

And also the maximum reached at (1,1,1) (Can also be found using concave Jensen)

Comment: EV is powerful.

Comment: @RiverLi can you please explain two things about my solution that I just claimed are true.1) how do I know that n-1Ev doesn't push numbers off the interval. 2) how could I have done what I did with sturms by hand?

Comment: Actually, since $f(x)$ is concave on $[0, c]$ and convex on $[c, 3]$ for some $c$. You can assume that $x_1 \le x_2\le x_3$. There are two cases: $x_1, x_2 \in [0, c]$ or $x_2, x_3 \in [c, 3]$.

Comment: for question 2), I have no idea.